# Least cost path

Tags: qgis, cost-path

I'm assuming (perhaps wrongly) that the least cost path analysis in QGIS uses a number of steps out from the active cell in calculating the best route. If so, is there a way to increase the forward steps? I've run several goes on both an elevation and slope grid and it is obviously taking into account the adjoining cells rather than forward stepping out to a broader radius. The result are long deviations around topography when other shorter options are obvious, albeit covering short distances of steeper terrain.

Comment: Can you edit your question and specify what tool you used and exactly how you prepared your cost layer from your slope and elevation.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Have you considered marking the "Knight's move" box? It makes the algorithm able to step one cell in the way a knight moves on a chess board. Now, as @user2856 mentionned, it would be better if you showed exactly the context you're getting the problem.